# Copying a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to copy a table (with definition, constraints, identity) to a new table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not really, you have to script it out, then change the names

you can do this

```
select * into NewTable
FROM OldTable
WHERE 1 =2 --if you only want the table without data
```

but it won't copy any constraints

Comment: so we can't do without prior creation of new table definition?

Comment: This will create the table definition but it won't have any of the constraint, keys etc etc

Answer (score 1):

- Generate a CREATE script based on the table
- Modify the script to create a different table name
- Perform an INSERT from selecting everything from the source table

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant solution, but you could use a tool like the free [Database Publishing Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en) from Microsoft.
It creates an SQL script of the table definition including data and including indexes and stuff. But you would have to alter the script manually to change the table name...

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:
I just found [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521611/t-sql-scripts-to-copy-all-table-constraints/1521892#1521892) on SO.
This script is an example to script the constraints of **all** tables, but you can easily change it to select only the constraints of "your" table.

So, you could do the following:

1. Create the new table with data like SQLMenace said (select * into NewTable from OldTable)
2. Add constraints, indexes and stuff by changing this SQL script